# How can I save data from intent to text file to documents folder?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am receiving an object that I want to save with timestamp to text file in the phone's documents folder. I have currently added the permissions lines to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```js
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Getting it to save `.txt` to downloads folder. But there is nothing in the file and the size is 0mb.

```
    private fun saveFile() {

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "text/plain"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "device.txt")
            // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
            // the system file picker before your app creates the document.
            //putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, createFile)
    }
```

```js
private var measureLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        Log.d(result.resultCode.toString(), "code ${result.resultCode}")

        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // There are no request codes
            tvPalaute?.text = getString(R.string.status_ok)

            val data: Intent? = result.data

            if (data != null) {
                val measureData = data.getStringExtra("M")

                if (measureData != null) {
                    val date = Date()
                    Timestamp(date.time)
                    Log.d(date.toString(), "date")

                    tvPalaute?.text = getString(R.string.status_ok) + "\n \n" + measureData

    }
```

I have tried following things to save the measureData to text file.

But none of those worked and crashed the application with error something related to file read only.

```
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Comment: Which action did you start with what you call intent?

Comment: It is unclear which uri you use to open an output stream.

Comment: Thing is i don't have uri. The intent opens another application to do something and then returns to the application and returns me some data. In this case I will get ```{"mode": "nameoftheselectedmode", ...}``` which is an object @blackapps I updated also the question

Comment: `val uri = getDevice
                OutputStream = getContentResolver. openOutputStream(uri, "String")
              ` You dont have an uri?

Comment: It looks pretty irrelevant to me that data would come from what you call an intent. You can remove all your intent code. Then just start with a variable that contains the data and try to save that variable. Pay attention to your read only uri. Show us what you use.

Comment: It's just a string that contains name of the device. @blackapps

Comment: Show exactly what you have. Put it in your code so we see what you do. And an uri would be more than a name of course. And it should contain the Documents folder...

Comment: @blackapps I updated with all relevant code to what I am trying to do. Basically I get this measureData which is an object that is following format `{"mode": "nameoftheselectedmode", ...}` and I am trying to save this to the text file with timestamp

Comment: Irrelevant all. Too much code commented. Use only openFileOutput("measurement.txt, .... And complete code for it. Realise that the file would never land in Documents folder then.

Comment: I updated the answer with the latest attempt. It indeeds saves the file but it goes `data/data/com.example.app` instead of going to documents. It also overwrites the existing text in there instead creating new line @blackapps

Comment: Yes, all expected behaviour. Try something else. Basic excercise.